# Create new column and fill all rows with the same field values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that rates outfits. I want to take the value of predicted rating when predicted month = base month and fill it into rows with the same base month, shirt, pants, and shoes in a new column called actual rating, as shown below.

| predicted month | base month | shirt | pants | shoes | predicted rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.2 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0.6 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0.3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0.1 |

I bolded the rows which predicted month = base month.

Eg. Since the first 2 rows have the same base month, shirt, pants, shoes as the third row, whose predicted month = base month, I want to take the third row's predicted rating and fill it in to actual ratings of rows 1-3. How can I do this?

Eg. I want to take the 4th row's predicted rating and fill it in to actual ratings of rows 5-6

| predicted month | base month | shirt | pants | shoes | predicted rating | Actual rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.2 | 0.5 |
| **0** | **0** | **1** | **1** | **1** | **0.5** | 0.5 |
| **1** | **1** | **2** | **2** | **1** | **0.6** | 0.6 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.6 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.6 |

There is no order of which the database is ordered. The last row could be the first.

I've tried partition by and looked for ways to do this still don't know how. Is this possible with SQL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can use *First_Value()* for this:

```
select *,
  First_Value(predictedRating) over(partition by baseMonth order by predictedMmonth) as ActualRating
from t;
```

Comment: Hi @Stu! Thanks for the quick answer! Do you mind explaining this in layman's terms? I am quite new to SQL. :)

Comment: First_Value is known as a *window function* - the *over* partitions rows essentially into "windows" or groups, so this groups them by the BaseMonth column, then as the name suggests returns the first value of each group for the specified column, predictedRating, according to the specified ordering. This assumes (from your data) the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` combined with conditional aggregation.  This answer assumes that the "third" row per group is characterized by having the earliest predicted month value.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [base month], shirt, pants, shoes
                                 ORDER BY [predicted month]) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT [predicted month], [base month], shirt, pants, shoes, [predicted rating],
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [predicted rating] END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY [base month], shirt, pants, shoes) AS [Actual rating]
FROM cte
ORDER BY [base month], shirt, pants, shoes, [predicted month] DESC;
```

Comment: Hi @ Tim Biegeleisen! Thank you for your quick answer! My apologies for sorting the row example by 3's. I have edited my example table accordingly. The data is not sorted in any way and the last row could well be the first. Would this query still work?

Comment: You must provide the logic for how to identify the row to retain per group.  Otherwise, your question can't be answered.